# Why are CSS animations not happening until I click any where in the canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, css-animations

When my page initially loads, animation transforms for the menu are not working and the submenu items just appear.  However, when I click anywhere on the canvas or even click to drag the scroll the animations work again. If I scroll with keyboard or page up/down it's stays the same.  What could be wrong here?  Is there a fix to this?

This is an issue as without the animation, there is a dead zone that hides the menu.  When animation works, the deadzone doesn't happen.

SITE: https://www.kuulu.fi/

VIDEO: https://youtu.be/FB24v9RRM6I

This happens in both Firefox and Chrome on Linux. (Have not checked others.)

Comment: Works fine for me. Note though that linking to off-site resources to explain your question doesn't help future visitors if the source is ever removed. Try to include the minimal code necessary to replicate the problem here on Stack Overflow. **Note**: tested in _Chrome Version 73.0.3683.86 (Official Build) (64-bit) for Windows 10_

Comment: It work well for me too. Have you checked again? Chrome: 73.0.3683.86

Comment: I went to a chrome on mac with the same issue.  Not my computer.  I will check a windows computer when I get near one.

Comment: Chrome for Windows produces the same result.  I don't think you guys are seeing the issue.  Try hard refreshing to see if it has any change.  That's how I was able to reproduce it on computer that haven't seen the site before.